# Arch Linux cfdisk asking for disk label type

Tags: arch-linux, partition, hard-disk, cfdisk

I am trying to partition my hard drive I just wiped with dban so that I can install arch linux but when i run

```
cfdisk /dev/sda
```

It says:

```
Select table type
gpt
dos
sgi
sun
```

I don't know which to choose.

It also says:

```
Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
```

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide#Partition_table_types

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at that. I wasn't able to find a resource like that

Answer (score 6):

Choose `gpt` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) for harddisks bigger than 2 TB and machines using UEFI and `dos` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) otherwise.

A general descrition regarding this topic you can on the Wikipedia article about Partition tables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table).

Comment: "Choose `gpt` for harddisks bigger than 2 TB and machines using UEFI and `dos` otherwise." - should this be interpreted as `gpt` for > 2TB *and* UEFI, or do you mean >2 TB *or* UEFI? I.e. if the disk is, say, 512GB but the machine is UEFI, what then?

Comment: @meowsqueak: It's >2TB and UEFI. `dos` won't work if  both of these are present. It will work with UEFI by itself but not >2TB by itself. (edited because of an incorrect answer)